# UIButton extend touch area like apple keyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, keyboard

I have a view with three small custom UIButtons (w:25,h:35) and I feel its really hard to get the touch events.

I have added target for touchUpInside event.

> [button addTarget:self action:@selector(keyPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

But as I said I myself seem to miss it easily. Then I looked into similar buttons in apple's keyboard. They seem to have a much bigger touch area, specially the keys with alphabet `"A"` and `"L"`. I am wondering how they have managed to do the same.

Any help and code sample would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make a new class that enherits UIButton and override this function:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
int errorMargin = 8;
if ([self.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"A"] || [self.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"a"]) {
    CGRect largerFrame = CGRectMake(0 - 20, 0 - errorMargin, self.frame.size.width + 22, self.frame.size.height + errorMargin*2);
    return (CGRectContainsPoint(largerFrame, point) == 1) ? self : nil;
}
if ([self.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"L"] || [self.titleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"l"]) {
    CGRect largerFrame = CGRectMake(0 - 2, 0 - errorMargin, self.frame.size.width + 20, self.frame.size.height + errorMargin*2);
    return (CGRectContainsPoint(largerFrame, point) == 1) ? self : nil;
}

CGRect largerFrame = CGRectMake(0 - 2, 0 - errorMargin, self.frame.size.width + 2, self.frame.size.height + errorMargin*2);
return (CGRectContainsPoint(largerFrame, point) == 1) ? self : nil;
}
```

you will get the same visual output and the touchable area that you want

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn´t create a button smaller than 40x40 points. You can put a smaller image in it. You can have an image with is 25,35 (b.e. myImage@2x.png).

An example:

```
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 40, 40)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

// Other option

```
    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(myPosition.x-15, myPosition.y-15, 40, 40)];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myImage"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 // ......
button.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor clearColor] CGColor];
button.layer.borderWidth = 15.0;
button.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Comment: I am not using an image, i am adding the keys from interface builder and using background color.

Comment: Ok, In this case you can use a proportional dimension (in this case +15). Your new buttons is : w:40 h:50. And you add a clear border. And It´s look is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Edge Insets?

This basically let's you set inset or outset margins for the rectangle around the button.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uibutton_class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006815-CH3-SW31